# Parent div to match tallest child div's height?

Tags: css, html, web, height

I'm making a website with a "page" div, and inside that contains the left div "navigation" and the right div "content". I want to make the height of the "page" div (so the background matches) equal to the height of the tallest div, either "navigation" or "content".

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8):

write like this

html:

```
<div class="page">
 <div class="navigation"></div>
 <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
page{overflow:hidden}
.navigation, content{float:left}
```

Comment: Well, adding style='overflow: hidden' worked to add to the "page" div. Thanks to mu is too short, but you still wrote "overflow:hidden" so yeah. I'll give you an up vote, but I'll save best answer for mu is too short if he posts an answer to top off his comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're floating the other divs, otherwise this would always be the case.  You can either float the parent div as well, or add a `<div style='clear: both'></div>` just before the end of the parent div.  Either of these techniques will cause the parent div to be as big as its children.

EDIT: whoops, missed the end tag :)

Comment: Or `overflow: hidden` on the "page" div.

Comment: Okay, so the original style='clear : both' didn't work, and I didn't try doing the other option, but, thank you mu is too short, your tip worked! Thank you! Too bad you didn't post an answer instead (can you do it now?) I can't give you best answer, but you got it! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Keavon: You'd want to put the `<div style='clear: both'></div>` right at the bottom of the "page" div, that should be the same visual effect as `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="navigation">i am navigation</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est maiores, ex? Mollitia assumenda veniam aliquid commodi ex, libero in quia perspiciatis sint voluptatibus soluta exercitationem quas quos repudiandae deserunt obcaecati.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .page {
  background-color: #000;
 }
 /* for clearfix*/
.page:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;   
 }
 /* for clearfix end*/

 .navigation,.content {
   float: left;
 }
 .navigation {
   width: 20%;
   background-color: #cd6a51;
 }
 .content {
   width: 80%;
   background-color: #4CAF50;
 }
```